# Text align centre while stacking

Tags: html, css

I have some text that ive gotten to align centre correctly. Its currently over a video background. What im wanting it to do is align the text centre all the time while scaling, even what it stacks above each other.

for example:

```
The cat ate the hat while
   sitting on the matt
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/14kd3L55/3/
The thing needing to be centred correctly is the quote

HTML:

```
<div class="landing_wrap">
    <div class="quote">
        <p>cat ate a hat while sitting on the mat there was even a bat</p>
    </div>
    <div class="landing">
```

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------- Default Layout ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.wrapper{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------- Landing Layout ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.quote{
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
    top:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#aaa;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:2em;
    text-align:centre;
    z-index:4000;
}
.landing_wrap{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.landing{
    height:1000px;
    min-height:660px; !important
}
#landingbg {
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a little trick to achieve that:

```
.quote {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: it gets the text to do what I wanted, but pushes it off screen. Any way to bring it back to the centre of the page? and keep doing what its doing?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you. Here is a fiddle. What is wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/14kd3L55/4/

Comment: oh damn! nevermind, forgot I had some @media things going, so when i scaled it my side it did weird stuff. Thanks that worked perfectly!